# How to detect browser features like History API, localStorage, etc on first request?

Tags: java, html, jsf, browser

Is there any way to detect the browser features like History API, localStorage, etc **on first request received from client** on server so that I could customize the response page data as per the browser features?

I know how to do it while page is loaded(I do it using `Modernizr` JS library).

Comment: Your tags say "html" and "browser", but it sounds like you want to do something on the server side. What language are you writing in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set a cookie on the first page load. If said cookie does not exist, check for features. Pseudo:

```
if(feature_cookies_does_not_exist) {
   check_for_features()
   create_feature_cookie()
}
```

Comment: cookie is sent on every request to server, hence, is there any alternate ?

Comment: A better question is: how dow `create_feature_cookie()` work? How does the server determine the browser's features?

Comment: @Barmar: I guess creating cookie would be done client side only & presence of cookie would be checked server side